# How to use vuetify with laravel 6

Tags: laravel, vuetify.js, laravel-6

I'm using Vuetify toolbar component inside home.blade.php, my problem is that i want to add some css styling to the component. where i can add the styling ?

I try to add the styling in the resources/sass/app.scss file but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change sass files you need to build them via `npm run dev`. This will build the `public/css/app.css` file that you have to include in your `blade` file, for example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}">
```